# Formatting a date is giving me a different one from the passed one

Tags: javascript

I need to get the first and last day of the current month, this works perfectly but when I format the date to looks like this `yyyy/mm/dd` it changes from the one I passed

For example, if a passed the 1 May 2020 when I format the date returns me the 30 April 2020

```js
var startID = document.getElementById('start');
var datenow = new Date();
var firstday = new Date(datenow.getFullYear(), datenow.getMonth(), 1);
firstday = firstday.toISOString().slice(0, 10);
startID.value = firstday;
```

```html
<input type="date" name="start" class="form-control" id="start" required autofocus>
<label for="start">Start Date</label>
```

This is how I get the first day of the current month:

```js
var datenow = new Date();
var firstday = new Date(datenow.getFullYear(),datenow.getMonth(), 1);
```

This is how I format the date to looks like `yyyy/mm/dd` in this part is where I get another wrong date from the passed one:

```js
firstday = firstday.toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Comment: What's the date you expect and the wrong date that you get ?

Comment: @mrid I want to get the first day of the current month in the format `yyy/mm/dd`. And I got the 2020/04/30

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of the problem is in the use of **getMonth()** method to obtain the month number.

The **getMonth()** method returns integers from 0 to 11 (January = 0, ...Dec = 11).

The problem can be fixed by adding 1 to getMonth().

**Here is a working example to show current date, first day and last day:**

```
var now = new Date()
console.log("Today = " + now)

let month = (now.getMonth() + 1)
let year = now.getFullYear()

firstDay = ("1/" + month + "/" + year)
lastDay = ((new Date(year, month, 0)).getDate() + "/" + month + "/" + year)

console.log("First day = " + firstDay)
console.log("Last day = " + lastDay)
```

**Output:**

```
Today = Sat May 30 2020 20:54:56 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
First day = 1/5/2020
Last day = 31/5/2020
```

**More information:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth

Comment: As I explained before the problem is not there when I do the getMonth() worked perfectly, the problem is when I tried to format the date

Comment: I updated the answer with a working example code that uses (getMonth() + 1) to obtain the current month.

Answer (score 0):

Timezones are tricky! Any given timestamp could look like a different date  depending on your timezone. ISO strings ignore timezone. So for starters, you could just do `new Date().toString()`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I already did `toString()`  but doesn't bring me any the date in this case when I tried to put format

Answer (score 0):

That happens because `firstday.toISOString()` returns date in UTC timezone so if you're located somewhere else you can expect the shifts in dates.

Unfortunately there is no go-to solution if you're not using something like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) (and it does not seem to be appropriate for such a simple task). I'd recommend you something like:

```
const [day, month, year] = firstday.toLocaleDateString('en-US').split('.');
firstday = [year, month, day].join('/')
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying me that. Do you know how can I solve the issue?

Comment: I've updated the answer and added possible take to your problem

Answer (score 0):

use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to properly format dates and perform date related operations. it makes thing fairly easier to implement.